Merge and synonymize [cdp] with [chrome-devtools-protocol]

cdp is a new tag with 35 questions
chrome-devtools-protocol is the main tag with 199 questions

The term "CDP" is a well-known abbreviation for "Chrome Devtools protocol", so it makes sense to synonymize the tags and optionally retag cdp to chrome-devtools-protocol.

We have at least one question using CDP for Cloudera Data Platform so it might need disambiguated first. It also might be a better blocklist candidate if there are more meanings for CDP.

It looks like there's a tag [tag:cloudera-cdp] which has several questions also tagged [cdp].

There's also at least one about the "concrete delivery problem".  That really cements this as a problem tag.

~10 questions for cloudera, 1 for "Concrete Delivery Problem", 1 for Apache Unomi
"Customer Data Platform"

My vote would be to get rid of the tag then. Retag all the non-Chrome-related questions, merge the remaining CDP into Chrome Devtools protocol, destroy the tag, and don't create any synonyms.

@HenryEcker agreed, with one additional step: create a new [chrome-cdp] tag as a synonym for [chrome-devtools-protocol], so as to surface it when a user types "cdp".

I think the 22 remaining [tag:cdp] questions are all about chrome devtool protocols. If someone would double check that and let me know I'll do the merge.

AFAICT How to get a success callback of session expire (inactivity) in Apache Unomi 2.0 is about Apache Unomi "Customer Data Platform". Everything else seems correct.

Pursuant the discussion in the comments, we've instead opted to delete the cdp. Its overlap with Customer Data Platforms of various flavours created too much ambiguity to be a good synonym candidate for chrome-devtools-protocol.
Given the small initial number of questions (35) and the moderator, trusted user, and SME contributions, the criteria for the abridged burnination process were met. I went ahead and retagged the non-Chrome-devtools-protocol-related questions. The vast majority were retagged cloudera-cdp with a few that merely had the tag removed as not applicable.
I went ahead and created the synonym suggested by RyanM chrome-cdp which allows chrome-devtools-protocol to surface when adding tags:

I merged the remaining cdp questions into chrome-devtools-protocol, deleted the cdp tag, and left it unsynonymised.
updating post history, 22 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 20 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 19 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'cdp': [cdp] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 history records for type Announcement had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Announcement had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 history records for type Collectives Discussion had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Collectives Discussion had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 218
tag remapping of [chrome-devtools-protocol] and [cdp] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
32 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!

If the cdp tag reappears with some frequency, please consider creating a new blocklist-request.
